# Please explain why I am able to instantiate the "Application" interface in Excel VSTO

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I have the following C# code in my application which works just fine.  It launches a new instance of Excel.

```
private readonly Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application _application;
_application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
_application.Visible = true;
```

I only recently noticed that [Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.application.aspx) is an interface type.  What exactly is going on and how is it possible?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The compiler allows you to instantiate interfaces if they’re decorated with a [`CoClass`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.coclassattribute.aspx) attribute identifying the concrete class that implements them (as well as a [`ComImport`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comimportattribute.aspx) and a [`Guid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.guidattribute.aspx)). When you instantiate the interface, you would actually be instantiating this concrete class behind-the-scenes.

This “feature” is intended to be used as plumbing for COM imported types. Notice how the Outlook [`Application`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.application.aspx) interface is backed by a concrete class named [`ApplicationClass`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.applicationclass.aspx):

```
[GuidAttribute("00063001-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
[CoClassAttribute(typeof(ApplicationClass))]
public interface Application : _Application, ApplicationEvents_11_Event
```

In most circumstances, you should *not* go applying these attributes to your own interfaces. However, for the sake of demonstration, we can show that the compiler *will* allow you to take advantage of this possibility for instantiating interfaces in your code. Consider the following simple example (the GUID is random):

```
[ComImport]
[Guid("175EB158-B655-11E1-B477-02566188709B")]
[CoClass(typeof(Foo))]
interface IFoo
{
    string Bar();
}

class Foo : IFoo
{
    public string Bar()
    {
        return "Hello world"; 
    }
}
```

Using the above declarations, you can create an instance of your own `IFoo` interface:

```
IFoo a = new IFoo();
Console.WriteLine(a.Bar());
// Output: "Hello world"
```

**Edit**: Although [jonnyGold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039064/please-explain-why-i-am-able-to-instantiate-the-application-interface-in-excel/11039870#comment14438702_11039870) correctly notes that the Excel [`Application`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.application.aspx) instance is not decorated with `CoClass` on MSDN, this appears to be an MSDN omission. The decompiled signature from the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` assembly is:

```
[CoClass(typeof(ApplicationClass)), Guid("000208D5-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
[ComImport]
public interface Application : _Application, AppEvents_Event
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation.  I'm now left wondering "why?", but I assume a good understanding of COM interop would be pre-requisite to that.

Comment: My unsubstantiated guess is that this was a “hack” introduced into the .NET compiler purely for addressing some legacy requirements while interoperating with COM.

Comment: According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.application.aspx) `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application` isn't decorated with the `CoClassAttribute`, but it must be.  Admittedly, I have not used dotPeek on the assmebly in question.

Comment: @jonnyGold: Yes, that was the reason I didn’t paste the Excel `Application` signature for my example. Replied in answer with decompiled signature.

Comment: Just opened it up in dotPeek and verified that Application is decorated with [CoClass(typeof(ApplicationClass))].

Answer (score -2):

Because [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247302%28v=office.11%29.aspx) says so:

> For example, the following code uses the Excel Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application interface.
>   At run time, it uses the Application class to instantiate an Excel Application object and open a worksheet.

Comment: Hardly a satisfactory answer… MSDN also says “An interface cannot be instantiated directly.”

Comment: Agreed.  The article doesn't explain how that is even syntactically valid.  Nor does the library documentation.