# COMException C# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Tags: c#, excel, comexception

I am trying to solve an issue I am having with a COMException. This is my code:

The error occurs at Workbook Original = new Workbook(result[0]);

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using MahApps.Metro.Controls;
using MahApps.Metro;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using System.Data;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;




namespace KPI_Generator_v3
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : MetroWindow
{

    string [] result;
    Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void exit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();

    }

    private void browse_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        // Create OpenFileDialog 
        instructionslbl.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        dlg.Multiselect = true;
        dlg.ShowDialog();
        result = dlg.FileNames;
        dlg.DefaultExt = ".xls";
        dlg.Filter = "XLS Files (*.xls)|*.xls";

        foreach (string fileName in result)
        {
            displayFilesBox.Text += fileName + System.Environment.NewLine;

        }

        SelectedFileslbl.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        displayFilesBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        generateBtn.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

    }

    private void generate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Workbook Original = new Workbook(result[0]);
        for (int i = 1; i <= result.Length; i++)
        {

            Workbook next = new Workbook(result[i]);
            Worksheet newOGsheet = Original.Worksheets.Add();
            Worksheet nextSheet = next.Worksheets[0];
            nextSheet.Copy(newOGsheet);
        }



    }


    }
 }
```

Now.. Although the above code will probably not work I am getting an error that states

'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

with additional information saying

HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))

After googling for quite some time I have downloaded dependency walker and have the following output:

[image]

I have no idea what I am doing and some help would be much appreciated! Thank you

EDIT: REGEDIT picture of HKEY CLASSES_ROOT (if needed)

[image]

EDIT2: Picture of error

[image]

Comment: What line do you get the error on? From the code I can see one bug here `for (int i = 1; i <= result.Length; i++)` . I think it needs to be `for (int i = 1; i < result.Length; i++)` notice `<=` changed to  `<`. You are exceeding the result array by 1.

Comment: The error is on line 74 @ Workbook Original = new Workbook(result[0]); I believe my system does not have something registered properly. When I try to regsvr32 the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll I get an error. Also, I am posting a picture of regedit at the HKEY CLASSES_ROOT value

Comment: By the way, these types of exceptions seem to commonly happen when you're using Office Interop. You might want to switch to something [Open Office XML SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854(v=office.15).aspx) or [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/), as they are entirely in the .NET framework and don't rely on COM to communicate to external libraries.

Comment: You cannot create WorkBook objects yourself, you have to use a factory function.  Use Application.WorkBooks.Add() instead.  Very common in the Office object model btw.  There is a ton of example code out there to help avoid simple mistakes like this.

Answer (score 2):

This error is a COM interop flaw unfortunately. Otherwise, you would be getting a compile error, since `Workbook` is an interface and doesn't have a constructor. This interface isn't meant to be instantiated, which is why you are getting this exception. (Not sure why you're passing in the filename here as well...)

To fix this, use [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel.application(v=office.15).aspx)

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Application excelApp = new Application();
excelApp.Workbooks.Open(result[0]);
```

Other notes:

- You should call `dlg.ShowDialog()` last - that way, your filters will take effect.
- For your filter, I suggest adding an option for .xlsx files, to support newer Excel files
- Add `result.Length > 0` before using it, just to make sure the user actually opened something.
- Change your for loop condition to `i < result.Length`; otherwise, you'll get an `IndexOutOfRangeException`

Also, just to add more information: you may be asking: "but wait, ryrich, `Application` is an interface too! How come I can instantiate **it** but not `Workbook`??"

I wondered this too. Apparently this works because it is decorated with a `CoClassAttribute` (and some other attributes). For more detailed information about this, see **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039064/please-explain-why-i-am-able-to-instantiate-the-application-interface-in-excel)** stack overflow post.

Comment: @MichaelPetch ok, I'll add that in.

Comment: Looks good. Between the two of us we covered it all off in your answer. I have removed mine (even though it had upvotes). We can focus on your answer.