# How to get CustomDocumentProperties using Excel Interop?

Tags: c#, excel, interop, vsto

The below code is used to get the custom document properties for Excel workbook.

```
var xlApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application; // This works in VSTO Excel Add-in
var xlApp = new global::Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application(); // This doesn't work anywhere
xlApp.Visible = true;
global::Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(file, false, true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

global::Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperties properties = workbook.CustomDocumentProperties; // Exception occurs here
global::Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperty property = properties["propertyname"];
```

The first 2 lines are references to the Excel `Application`. One obtain the reference from VSTO add-in internals, the other is a regular `new Application()`.

When using the `Application` from VSTO internals, the code run fines without any problems. But when using `new Application()`, the `workbook.CustomDocumentProperties` line throws `InvalidCastException`:

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface
>   type 'Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperties'. This operation failed
>   because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface
>   with IID '{2DF8D04D-5BFA-101B-BDE5-00AA0044DE52}' failed due to the
>   following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

I am trying to make it to work on a C# winforms project without VSTO. A lot of examples and tutorials use `new Application()` for Excel interop, but I noticed that `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application` is an interface, so using `new` on interface is actually strange to me. How can I create a proper Application that can get the `CustomDocumentProperties`?

Reference Assemblies I am using:

- Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel v2.0.50727 Version 14.0.0.0
- Microsoft.CSharp v4.0.30319 Version 4.0.0.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I  noticed that Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application is an interface, so using new on interface is actually strange to me.

That is strange indeed, but by design. The `Excel.Application` interface is decorated with the `CoClass` attribute telling the actual class to instantiate on 'instantiating' the interface. More about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039064/please-explain-why-i-am-able-to-instantiate-the-application-interface-in-excel).

> But when using `new Application()`, the `workbook.CustomDocumentProperties` line throws `InvalidCastException`:

Strange indeed again. I have experienced some issues myself using document properties. It seems that the actual class returned differs from the spec, so I moved to use `dynamic` in order to prevent type casting issues.

So instead of this:

```
Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperties properties = workbook.CustomDocumentProperties;
```

Use:

```
dynamic properties = workbook.CustomDocumentProperties;
```

Comment: Changing both `DocumentProperties`  and `DocumentProperty` to dynamic actually works! But not sure if relying on `dynamic` is a good practice? Is there no way to ensure the correct type that the code is dealing with to prevent further possible runtime problems?

Comment: Not as far as I know. Actually a lot of the interop classes are using `dynamic` for this exact reason.

Comment: I find it comical that the Microsoft Web pages on this generate the noted error, thanks Patrick Hofman!

Answer (score 0):

> How can I create a proper Application that can get the CustomDocumentProperties?

There is no need to create a new Excel Application instance if you develop an add-in. You should use the Application property provided by the VSTO runtime:

```
var xlApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application; // This works in VSTO Excel Add-in
```

But if you develop a standalone application which automates Excel, in that case you need to create a new Application instance by using the new operator:

```
var xlApp = new global::Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
```

Use the late binding technology (Type.InvokeMember) for getting or setting document property as the [How To Use Automation to Get and to Set Office Document Properties with Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303296/en-us)  article suggests.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a same problem. Today it has been resolved. There is a different approach to derive the results. The question and its' answer is at

[How can I read excel custom document property using c# excel interop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59683995/how-can-i-read-excel-custom-document-property-using-c-sharp-excel-interop)

Here is my implementation.

```
public string CheckDocProp(string propName, object props)
        {
            Excel.Workbook workBk = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook;

            object customProperties = workBk.CustomDocumentProperties;
            Type docPropsType = customProperties.GetType();
            object nrProps;
            object itemProp = null;
            object oPropName;
            object oPropVal = null;

            nrProps = docPropsType.InvokeMember("Count",
                BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.Default,
                null, props, new object[] { });
            int iProps = (int)nrProps;

            for (int counter = 1; counter <= ((int)nrProps); counter++)
            {
                itemProp = docPropsType.InvokeMember("Item",
                    BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.Default,
                    null, props, new object[] { counter });

                oPropName = docPropsType.InvokeMember("Name",
                    BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.Default,
                    null, itemProp, new object[] { });

                if (propName == oPropName.ToString())
                {
                    oPropVal = docPropsType.InvokeMember("Value",
                        BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.Default,
                        null, itemProp, new object[] { });
                    return oPropVal.ToString();
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    return "Not Found.";
                }
            }
            return "Not Found.";
        }
```

Usage:

```
object docProps = wb.CustomDocumentProperties;
            string prop1 = ExistsDocProp("<CustomProperty>", docProps);
```